# Netsuite Nested CASE

Tags: case, netsuite

I've been working on a Nested Case statement for a `NetSuite` Workflow, and it is not evaluating beyond the first CASE WHEN. What is supposed to happen is when two check-boxes are checked, display two text phrases. When on or the other is checked, display the phrase that should be displayed for that checkbox.

The condition is

```
{entity.custentity__quality_control.id}='T' OR {entity.custentitypartnered_asp.id}='T'
```

My current code is:

```
CASE 
WHEN {entity.custentity__quality_control.id}='T' AND {entity.custentitypartnered_asp.id}='T' THEN 'QUALITY CONTROL - PARTNERED ASP'  
else 
    case WHEN {entity.custentity__quality_control.id}='F' THEN 'PARTNERED ASP' 
    else 
        case WHEN {entity.custentitypartnered_asp.id}='F' THEN 'QUALITY CONTROL'
        else ''
        end
    end 
END
```

Alternative formats I also tried are:

```
Case when a and b then c
when a = this and b <> that then c
when b=this and c <> that then c
else ''
end
```

In both cases, when a and b are true, then c happens as expected. However, if the first test fails, either the second and third tests do not process, or they fail and the else '' occurs.

The fields being tested are both checkboxes on the customer entity.  Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this? I only encapsulate you inner case statement with parentheses.

```
CASE WHEN {entity.custentity__quality_control.id}='T' AND {entity.custentitypartnered_asp.id}='T' THEN 'QUALITY CONTROL - PARTNERED ASP'
ELSE (
     CASE WHEN {entity.custentity__quality_control.id}='F' THEN 'PARTNERED ASP' 
     ELSE (
          CASE WHEN {entity.custentitypartnered_asp.id}='F' THEN 'QUALITY CONTROL'
          ELSE ''
          END
          ) 
     END
     ) 

END
```